# Изменив масштаб окна, у меня текст абсолютно поменял своё положение. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так?

Tags: html, css

Я новичок в веб-разработке. Работая над страницей, я свернул её и текст, который я создал в параграфе сместился. В чём дело?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Piroll</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<style>
    header {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: 100px;
    }
.logo {
margin-top: 38px;
margin-left: 100px;

}
.menu {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    min-height: 70%
    min-width: min-content;
}
}



</style>
<header>
<img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
<p class="menu"> HOME       ABOUT       WORK       PROCESS      SERVICES       TESTIMONIALS       CONTACT</p>
</header>


</body>
```

Вид страницы до и после изменения масштаба.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что  вашем классе `.menu` свойство `margin-left: 600px` вынуждает их.  Поставьте `margin-left: npx`, где n - длина logo

Comment: Убрав данное свойство, текст всё равно скатывается, уменьшая масштаб. Можно ли его как-то зафиксировать в данной позиции?

Comment: Скажем так, при очень резком уменьшении масштаба, текст упирается в логотип

Comment: @loel23, так а как вы хотите, чтобы текст выглядел, в случае его столкновения с логотипом? Поставьте "margin-left: npx", где n - длина logo

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @loel23, если ответ решил Вашу проблему, а Вы хотите чтобы и Вам дальше помогали на форуме, то кроме "спасибо", есть смысл добавить балов репутации, человеку который Вам помогал, проголосовав за его ответ.

Comment: ИМХО, есть смысл расширить ответ, добавив в него уточнения из комментариев.